# How to show full autocomplete suggestion in VS with native code (COM project reference)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autocomplete, com, native-code

I am working with a .Net 5 project with native code - a COM reference project: Interop.Excel 16, and it appears not to fully support autocomplete suggestion for COM instance. This is not just in case of C#, I met the same problem coding pywin32 with VSCode, no suggestion at all. There is not much documentation for these things as well.

Is there any solution for this? Looking forward to hearing from you!

Comment: Many objects are declared as `dynamic` in that interop assembly. For this type is not possible to make any suggestions, the members are simply unknown at compile time. Post a concrete example if dynamic is not involved, there are also other possibilities.

Comment: @Steeeve I think that is reasonable enough, but I hope would be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I find my own answer. The best practice is use the macro recorder in Excel. Then editing the macro source is very easy.